# PHP: compareTo similar to Java

Tags: php

In an effort to utilize OOP in PHP, I was looking for a way to define functions within objects to use for sorting. in Java this is simple, as the `compareTo()` is automatically called by sorted arrays and such. I looked around PHP.net and couldn't find anything similar in PHP. I have resorted to what seems like a hack to me, so I'm wondering if anyone can lend some insight on an easier way.

CURRENT CODE:

```
class SomeObject {
    private $someField;

    function getSomeField() { return $this->someField; }

    function compareTo($other) {
        return $this->someField - $other->getSomeField();
    }
}

//in funcs.php
function objSort($a, $b) {
    return $a->compareTo($b);
}


//To sort an array
usort($array, objSort);
```

Is there an easier/more sleek way of doing this in PHP?

Comment: Good question.  I don't believe you can have your own comparison operator function definitions in PHP, but I would be interested in seeing someone post an answer definitively either way.

Comment: In general, the answer to "is there a good way of doing this in PHP?" is "No."

Answer (score 2):

You could use anonymous function directly.

```
class SomeObject {
    private $someField;
    function getSomeField() { return $this->someField; }
}

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a->getSomeField() - $b->getSomeField();
});
```

Or you could define a static function use to compare.

```
class SomeObject {
    private $someField;

    function getSomeField() { return $this->someField; }

    static function compare($a, $b) {
        return $a->getSomeField() - $b->getSomeField();
    }
}

usort($array, array('SomeObject', 'compare'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this in PHP, although I would love to be proved wrong.  I usually have a package of utility classes for arrays, strings, numbers, etc. with static methods, but it's only useful if you are defining functions that PHP doesn't already have, as you are otherwise just making pointless wrappers for native functions.